# Why is the index getter of Storage return 'any' and not 'string | null' like getItem

Tags: typescript

I've been porting a project to TypeScript and noticed something odd.

the `Storage` object is used by the web browser to store session data. it has a convenience getter/setter using index methods. for example, `localStorage["username"]` retrieves that key.

my question is, why is it's syntax (see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/ece46113a57313be331554806ccdfdbef4d4395e/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L14595)):

`[name: string]: any;`

and not

`[name: string]: string | null;`

like the `getItem` method?

reason this comes up is because i expected to get warnings to handle the `null` case, but since it's coming in as an `any`, VSCode gives no warnings.

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason the indexer is `[name: string]: any` is because there are cases where it does not return a string, or a null, for example `['clear']` is actually a method.

The indexer must be compatible with all other members - and storage has a few methods as well as your data.

If you use `getItem` to retrieve the data, the type is `string | null` as expected.

Comment: great, thanks! is there a way they could have redefined it such that the indexer would exclude methods such as `clean`?

Comment: There's no feature that would allow that cleanly at the moment... there are some dirty ways to do it (the example in the link is a similar class of problem, not identical): https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/2018/11/typescript-dictarray-options/